# How to match a value UNLESS its capsulated within ()

Tags: regex

I got a solution to match the second part of a string, however i have have recently got an issue
My presumptions have been to see values such as:

```
XS
XS / S
30/30
30"/32"
```

However i have recently started to see values such as 40 (XS) and have been annoyed that i grab "XS" although i really wanted my regex to skip it, if the value is incapsulated in ()

My current regex:

```
(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))
```

Hope someone can help me avoid matching on these so i get proper data

Comment: You can exclude the parenthesis `(?:[^A-Za-z0-9()]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))` https://regex101.com/r/1YJXR2/1

Comment: Ahh i thought i had to escape it somehow

Comment: If the match should be at the start of the string, you might also use `^\w+[^\n\w()]+(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/oNhDqj/1

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the outer non capture group and exclude matching the parenthesis in the first character class

```
[^A-Za-z0-9()]+([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZG0e4S/1)

Note that the negated character class can also only match spaces and does not guarantee a non whitespace char other than a word char, so it could also match 40 in `30 40`

You might also use another character class specifying the characters that should be between the first and the second part.

```php
\w+\s*[/"]+\s*(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxIHhp/1)